Can a USB dock/hub damage the host hardware?
So i have a thinkpad x1 tablet gen3, a lenovo thunderbolt3 docking station, and a dell u2721DE display that is also a USB-C docking station (so one usbc cable that carries usb video and power, to the screen).
Lappie since late 2018, display since late 2020.
after i got the display the health of the laptop slowly began to degrade. first one usbc port where i used to plug the laptop stopped working properly.
Recently the laptop builtin display starts to show issues in particular after i use the laptop for a while with the external display through USBC (it boots blank and i have to reboot it many times before it shows anything, i did update all system and drivers).
So i resurrected the thunderbolt3 docking station to see if that would improve the situation. And i connected one usb port of the docking station to the display to use it as usb hub for mouse and keyboard.
Well, after a couple of days that port on the docking station died. and the port on the display is the same i previously used to connect the laptop directly.
I have the fw of the laptop and of the docking station up to date. For the display u2721DE there seems to be no fw updates.
So i wonder: can the screen be the responsible for equipment damage?

You are not alone. X1 gen3, lenovo usb-c docking, 60-80 hours per week 3 displays on and an occasional moving and using with other hubs. The same sympthoms + the ethernet port at the docking station died. My theory is that both devices degrade with time and use.

@fraxinus you mean it's not an issue of the display, but of the laptop/docking itself? I though that firmware update would fix the notorious alpine ridge issue, but from what you say, it could be that these devs are half dead and will die soon?
If this is the case, i wonder what usbc/tb controller is "safe".. and also what devices use it..

A general answer:
Interconnected hardware (electronics) do share voltages and signals.
If one device has problems and the problem is "visible" within an interconnection, then it is - at least theoretically - possible that a problematic device can cause problems also within other connected device(s).
Certain possibilities exist to isolate devices on interconnections, if "galvanical isolation" is stated in the datasheet of a device, then it generally uses circuitry that contains optics (LEDS++) to transfer signals... this is "good", assuming that you make sure to keep[1] the isolation.
[1] just a single grounding wire may be a "breaker" in this regard.
